# Не выводит значение mysql_insert_id()

Tags: php, mysql

```
$db = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `payments` (player_id, service, amount, time, status) VALUES ('$uid', '$method', '$insum', '$time', '0')");
echo mysqli_insert_id($db);
```

В базу добавляется строка с AUTO INCREMENT, нужно получить последний ID. С функцией  mysqli_insert_id() мне выводит пустоту, никаких значений. Юзал гугл ничего не нашел. Прошу помощи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `payments` (player_id, service, amount, time, status) VALUES ('$uid', '$method', '$insum', '$time', '0')");

echo mysqli_insert_id($connect);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло